# ColdFusion ORM, Hibernate - Retrieving most recent record for one-to-many field

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion

I have a custom property in a persistent cfc that looks like this:

```
property    name="last_live_request" 
        fieldtype="one-to-many" 
        cfc="Accreditation" 
        fkcolumn="pers_ky" 
        setter="false" 
        orderby="ACCR_KY desc" 
        where="status_doma_ky in (27,28) and rownum = 1"
;
```

The intention is to join to the Accreditation records, which are one-to-many, and retrieve only the most recent one. The problem is that it doesn't work.

Like in ordinary PL_SQL, the rownum is being evaluated before the sort, therefore I do not get the most recent record.

The solution for this in ordinary PL-SQL is to do a sub-select like this, so that we get the records first and then select the top record:

```
    select *
    from (
        select *
        from JOU_V_REV_PEACC 
        where status_doma_ky in (27,28)
        and pers_ky = [nnn]
        order by ACCR_KY desc
    )
    where rownum = 1
```

So my question is, how do I achieve this result in my cfc property?

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround:

```
// Get the max id using the formula attribute (note, requires SQL, not HQL)
property name="LAST_LIVE_ACCR_KY" setter="false" formula="
    select max(peac.accr_ky)
    from JOU_V_REV_PEACC peac
    where peac.status_doma_ky in (27,28)
    and peac.pers_ky = PERS_KY
";

// Set up the property
property name="last_live_request" persistent="false" default="";

// Load the required Accreditation using a custom function
function getlast_live_request() {
    return entityLoadByPK("Accreditation", this.attr('LAST_LIVE_ACCR_KY'));
}
```

Not so pretty, but effective.